# Layout.xml move element with custom condition

Tags: magento2, layout

I want move an element based on my helper custom return (True/False), i knew if config can link up with backend config, but is it possible to use a custom helper?

```
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search" 
ifconfig="\custom\helper??"/>
```

Is it possible to to that?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer is in the name...if config...helper isn't a config.

I would suggest a 'hack' though. Before renderring your webpage, like with a layout load before observer. Call your helper that will edit a specific configuration. This way you keep it dynamic.

but may be the better thing to do would be to use two different block / template depending on your helper call in the controller cause depending on what your helper does you could end up with lots of different configuration wich isn't realy relevant.